# error in testing restful

Tags: java, netbeans

what is the error at this project i am using netbeans 7.0.1

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [WebApplication] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 30; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'persistence-context-ref'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":display-name, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":icon, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":distributable, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":context-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":filter, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":filter-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":listener, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":servlet-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":session-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":mime-mapping, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":welcome-file-list, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":error-page, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":jsp-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-constraint, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":login-config, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":security-role, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":env-entry, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":ejb-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":ejb-local-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":service-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":resource-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":resource-env-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-destination-ref, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":message-destination, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee":locale-encoding-mapping-list}' is expected.. Please see server.log for more details.
    C:\Users\win-7\Desktop\WebApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:727: 
    The module has not been deployed.
        at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
        at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
        at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<web-app
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
     <servlet>
         <description>Generated servlet for Java ME Client to Web Application </description>
         <display-name>Javon service for  MyPackage.WebToMobileServlet</display-name>
         <servlet-name>WebToMobileServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>MyPackage.WebToMobileServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>WebToMobileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/MyPackage.WebToMobileServlet</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <session-config>
         <session-timeout>
             30
         </session-timeout>
     </session-config>
     <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list> 
     <persistence-context-ref> 
        <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/WebApplicationPU</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>WebApplicationPU</persistence-unit-name>
     </persistence-context-ref> 
     <resource-ref>
         <res-ref-name>UserTransaction</res-ref-name>
         <res-type>javax.transaction.UserTransaction</res-type>
         <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
     </resource-ref> 
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web.xml file is malformed, can you post it here?

The elemnet **persistence-context-ref** belongs to Java EE 5. Your web.xml should be using http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd schema not http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd

Changing only this will not fix the problem, your project was created for 1.4 spec and that tag is for Java EE 5 spec.

Recreate the project with the correct spec version or don't use that tag.

The header of the web.xml file must look like this:

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
```

Comment: an error when i chang the xml                        Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [WebApplication] : Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web]. Element [schema] is not a valid root element. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\win-7\Desktop\New folder (2)\WebApplication\nbproject\build-impl.xml:727: 
The module has not been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your web.xml is malformed or out of order.  Can you post it here and maybe we can eyeball the problem?

The web.xml is located in a directory called WEB-INF